# Setup Django Postgres database

Tags: django, postgresql, bitbucket

I created the django app, I have it connected to my local server with pgAdmin3. I want to have the django app push to bitbucket. But the problem is:

How do I setup Postgres database, so that everything I commit and push, my group member can pull and have the same data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bitbucket is used to host your source code, not your database data.**

If you setup a local database, only you, will be able to access these data. If you setup a remote database, you and your teammates will be able to access data. **But it's absolutely not recommended during development because each person are not working on the same task and database migration can mess up the work of one of your colleagues.**

If you want share data and populate your database during development, you are searching **fixtures** : [Django Wiki - Fixture](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Fixtures)

Fixtures files are a good way to share data to populate your database. Theses files can be versioned on Bitbucket.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'll try to put the database on a free server then.

Answer (score 0):

Step: 1

```
pip install psycopg2
```

For mac if you can’t install or the above command doesn’t work, use the following command instead, just add — binary

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

Step: 2 settings.py add configuration.

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'db_name', 
    'USER': 'db_user', 
    'PASSWORD': 'db_password',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1', # DB host
    'PORT': '5432', # DB port
}
```

}

Comment: Edit your answer and place `}` in code blocks properly, currently it is outside the blocks.